# How to add title or description into lightbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I have a gallery, I put there a lightbox but I don't know how to show the title or description of a picture in the lightbox. Now the 'title' is shown only on 'mouseenter' in the lightbox. I would like to have a row with the text under the picture. What should I do?

HTML:

```
        <a href="../img/animals/1_korytnacka.jpg" title="Turtle - 50 x 50 x 3,5 cm">
            <img src="../img/animals/1_thumb.jpg" alt="Korytnacka">
        </a>
```

JS:

```
var overlay = $('<div>', {
  id: 'overlay'
}).appendTo('body');
overlay.hide();

$('.gallery-set a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  overlay.empty().show();
  $('<img>', {
    src: $(this).attr('href'),
    alt: $(this).attr('alt'),
    title: $(this).attr('title')
  }).appendTo(overlay);
});

overlay.on('click', function() {
  $(this).hide();
});

$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  if(e.which == 27) {
    overlay.hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: You can always add a `paragraph` tag beneath the `img` and style that.

Comment: Do you want title to be displayed after clicking on image or before?

Comment: After clicking.

Answer (score 0):

Append the paragraph after the image in `on click` event function.

```js
var overlay = $('<div>', {
  id: 'overlay'
}).appendTo('body');
overlay.hide();

$('.gallery-set a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  overlay.empty().show();
  $('<img>', {
    src: $(this).attr('href'),
    alt: $(this).attr('alt'),
    title: $(this).attr('title')
  }).appendTo(overlay);
  $('<p>', {
    text: $(this).attr('title')
  }).appendTo(overlay);
});

overlay.on('click', function() {
  $(this).hide();
});

$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 27) {
    overlay.hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery-set">
  <a href="../img/animals/1_korytnacka.jpg" title="Turtle - 50 x 50 x 3,5 cm">
    <img src="../img/animals/1_thumb.jpg" alt="Korytnacka">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works fine :-) It works also without this: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>